# How can I Share different URL to every student of Google classroom using classroom api?

Tags: google-classroom

How can i share unique URl of any resources ( assignment or etc. ) to every student of google classroom using classroom api in angular 2?

Comment: Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here, read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the classroom API to create the courseWork then you have to assign separate courseWork/assignments and have to use **["individualStudentsOptions": {
    object(IndividualStudentsOptions)
  }](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork#CourseWork)**
field and for each student create a separate courseWork.
Check Out the link. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When the assigment is assigned there is only one attachment object for coursework. So you cannot have separate unique URI for each student. But when the student submits (Turns-In) his course work there is a unique attachment URL generated for that user which can be used to get to unique resource for that student (let's say a page that displays grade for that student only for that coursework). Having said that we can workaround this situation. We can always take the user to a common resource page and build logic in that page to redirect the user to unique URL based on student ID and courseworkID. Hope this helps.